# Why doesn't this loop want to work properly?

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop

I've been at this for hours but I want to be able to add another diver and the only thing I need to show  for it is the number of divers that were judged and their average score which I can do once this issue is fixed.

It runs but when it loops around, it skips city, and eventually crashes the 2nd to 3rd time around. 
Can anyone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    string city;
    double judge[4];

    double total = 0;
    double score;
    int divers = 1;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;

    do{
        cout << "Please enter divers name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Enter the diver's city: ";
        getline(cin, city);

        do{
            cout << "Enter the score given by judge #" << y << ": " ;
            cin >> judge[x];

            total = total + judge[x];

            y++;
            x++;
        } while(y < 6);

        y = 1;

        cout << "Divers?";
        cin >> divers;

    } while(divers == 1);

    cout << city << endl;
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << total << endl;
    cout << judge[0] << endl;
    cout << judge[1] << endl;
    cout << judge[2] << endl;
    cout << judge[3] << endl;
    cout << judge[4] << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: You want to add divers whereas your code only accepts one diver (while(divers == 1))....while(condition isn't true) is how the do-while loop works. Is that helpful?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `cin >> divers;` the end-of-line character is not removed from the input, just the number leading up to it. Then, the next time you ask for a line with `std::getline()` it returns just the end-of-line character that is already there and does not wait for your new input.

So when you do `cin >> drivers` style input **before** a `std::getline()` style input you need to read past the end-of-line character.

One way to do that is using the `ignore()` function:

```
do{
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "Please enter divers name: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter the diver's city: ";
    getline(cin, city);

    // ...
```

Another way is to use the white-space eater `std::ws` in your `std::getline()` calls:

```
do{
    cout << "Please enter divers name: ";
    getline(cin >> std::ws, name);
    cout << "Enter the diver's city: ";
    getline(cin >> std::ws, city);

    // ...
```

Strictly speaking only the first one is necessary. Remember the white-space eater will eat all the *initial* spaces you type into the `getline()` so you can't read in leading spaces if you use that technique.

Comment: You only have 4 judge[] locations and you go round the loop 5 times (I think). Remember that arrays count from `0` so your 4 judge[] locations are: `judge[0]; judge[1]; judge[2]; judge[3]`. So `0-3`. If `i` gets above 3 then you will access past the end of your array.

Answer (score 3):

indexing starts at 0 declaring `judge[4]` means you have `judge` indices as  0 1 2 3. You are accessing beyond the end of your arrays.

Comment: Array size declarations are not 0-based, if you want five judges, use 'double judge[5]'

Comment: @Aarix _" I can't get help like this anywhere else."_ The whacky thing is, you shouldn't have gotten help this way here at all. I.e. your question in itself isn't helpful for anyone else (the downvotes clearly indicate this).